# Debugger not Enabled

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, javascript-debugger

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Apache Cordova for developing Android Application. I got an Error

> code:-32000    message:Debugger agent is not enabled  The source map
>   'angular.min.js.map' for file 'D:\PHONEGAP\angular(v1.3.14).min.js'
>   could not be read from the specified location due to error 'Exception
>   of type 'TypeScriptSourceMapReader.SourceMapReadFailedException' was
>   thrown.'.

How to solve this Error?